# Array<T> or Slice<T> struct type understanding structure

Tags: swift, swiftype

While Array struct def is:

```
struct Array<T> : MutableCollection, Sliceable {
    typealias Element = T
    var startIndex: Int { get }
    var endIndex: Int { get }
    subscript (index: Int) -> T
    func generate() -> IndexingGenerator<[T]>
    typealias SliceType = Slice<T>
    subscript (subRange: Range<Int>) -> Slice<T>
}
```

while MutableCollection is:

```
protocol MutableCollection : Collection {
    subscript (i: Self.IndexType) -> Self.GeneratorType.Element { get set }
}
```

then Collection:

```
protocol Collection : Sequence {
    subscript (i: Self.IndexType) -> Self.GeneratorType.Element { get }
}
```

and then Sequence:

```
protocol Sequence {
    typealias GeneratorType : Generator
    func generate() -> GeneratorType
}
```

and Sliceable:

```
protocol Sliceable {
    typealias SliceType
    subscript (_: Range<Self.IndexType>) -> SliceType { get }
}
```

(Slice is almost equivalent to Array)

Where is the backstore ?

Comment: Does this answer your question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24073269/what-is-a-slice-in-swift ? - A slice points into an existing array. It does not have its own storage.

Comment: Thanks Martin, but what about struct Array<T>?

Comment: It's likely that the backing storage is not publicly visible. It also might be implemented in C rather than Swift.

Answer (score 0):

It's private. It used to be exposed as `ArrayBuffer`, but they removed that from the public headers (in beta 4 I believe). They do still (indirectly) expose the existence of `_ContiguousArrayBuffer` in beta 4.

The natural question is "why do you want to know?" The storage specifics are not a part of the interface of `Array`, so they're subject to change. Keep in mind that `Array` is independent of `ContiguousArray`, so almost anything you'd think you wanted to do with the backing storage probably wouldn't be safe anyway (since it's not even promised to be contiguous).

All that fancy-stuff said, you do in fact have access to something that is promised to *look* like the backing store. That's `withUnsafePointerToElements`. This will hand you a pointer that you are allowed to do pointer math on and get elements in the array (just like in C). (This method is in the header, but not the docs, so it may not survive the betas.)

You're also allowed to pass `&arrayT` to a C function that takes a `*T`, and it'll make it look like there really is a contiguous block of memory there. That's in the docs, so it's even more likely to stay true.

Comment: Thanks Rob for your response and advice.