# Subscript error in Swift Array

Tags: arrays, swift

I'm in the middle of implementing Merge Sort algorithm in Swift. 
Below is the function I made

```
func mergeSort(unsortedArray: [Int]) -> [Int] {
    guard unsortedArray.count > 1 else { return unsortedArray }

    let middleIndex = unsortedArray.count / 2

    let leftArray = mergeSort(unsortedArray: unsortedArray[0..<middleIndex])

    let rightArray = mergeSort(unsortedArray: unsortedArray[middleIndex..<unsortedArray.count])

    return merge(leftPile: leftArray, rightPile: rightArray)
}
```

On `leftArray` and `rightArray` declaration, I get an error saying,

```
Playground execution failed: error: MergeSort.xcplaygroundpage:4:59: error: cannot subscript a value of type '[Int]' with an index of type 'CountableRange<Int>'
    let leftArray = mergeSort(unsortedArray: unsortedArray[0..<middleIndex])
                                                          ^

MergeSort.xcplaygroundpage:4:59: note: overloads for 'subscript' exist with these partially matching parameter lists: (Int), (Range<Int>), (Range<Self.Index>), (ClosedRange<Self.Index>), (CountableClosedRange<Self.Index>)
    let leftArray = mergeSort(unsortedArray: unsortedArray[0..<middleIndex])
```

Can someone explain the issue over here? The answer key says that I should implement in a following way but I'm not sure why you would wrap an array within an array.

```
let leftArray = mergeSort(unsortedArray: Array(unsortedArray[0..<middleIndex]))

let rightArray = mergeSort(unsortedArray: Array(unsortedArray[middleIndex..<unsortedArray.count]))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're *not* wrapping an Array in an Array. You're coercing something that is *not* an Array *into* an Array. `unsortedArray[0..<middleIndex]` is not an Array. It is an ArraySlice, which is not the same thing. You need an Array here, so you coerce the ArraySlice to an Array.

Comment: So, that means he can use `Array(unsortedArray[0..<middleIndex])` right?

Comment: You could easily have discovered this by assigning `unsortedArray[0..<middleIndex]` to a variable and looking at the inferred type of that variable in QuickHelp. — See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24073269/what-is-a-slice-in-swift - Slice has changed its name to ArraySlice, but the point remains exactly the same.

Comment: @OrkhanAlikhanov He can and he _knows_ he can, because he is looking at the "answer key". His only question seems to be _why_. That is the question I'm answering.

Comment: Sorry for bothering. I didn't reach there. I saw you answered, so I left reading question and jumped into your answer.